# 503 error logging in using Python MechanicalSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

I want to scrape some information behind a login page but I get a 503

This is what happens when I try to login with mechanicalsoup (same result with robobrowser):

```
>>> import mechanicalsoup
>>> browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0')
>>> page = browser.get('https://X.com')
>>> page.status_code
200
>>> page = browser.get('https://X.com/wp-login.php')
>>> page.status_code
503
```

I've tried a couple of different user_agents, how can I get around this? moving cookies around?

Comment: Is `X.com` the real site, or just a placeholder? Can you access the page by typing its URL in a normal browser's URL bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I managed to do this using https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape

```
import cfscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# log in
scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()
scraper.get('https://X.com/wp-login.php')
tokens = cfscrape.get_tokens('https://X.com')
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(session=scraper, user_agent=tokens[1])
browser.select_form('#loginform')
browser['log'] = 'X'
browser['pwd'] = 'X'
browser.submit_selected()
browser.open('https://X.com/page/')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's protected by CloudFlare which is denying a pure GET request to that URL. You need a non-headless browser in order to access the page, otherwise it will reject it. Use a library such as [Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html) that provides a GUI and you should be fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # or whichever browser you prefer
browser.get('https://hacked.com/wp-login.php')
```

Note that there is no way to fetch a status code with Selenium. However, you have many more ways to interact with the page, and confirm that you have reached the page.

Comment: If it's only a matter of GET, MechanicalSoup can also send POST requests. More info about Selenium Vs MechanicalSoup in the FAQ: http://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: That may be, yes, but then how do you plan to access a login page with a POST request? :-)